# (Swift2 SpriteKit) How to transition between an SKScene and a UIViewController efficiently?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

There seems to be so many contradicting ideas on this topic. 
I simply wish to have my menu in a UIViewController and my game in the SKScene

In my SKScene I used:

```
        self.removeFromParent()
        self.view?.presentScene(nil)
```

The nodes are removed but the scene is still in place as I still have the grey background and fps counter. Can I return to the View aspect of the UIViewController and hide the scene?

My method one implementation:

RootViewController:

```
class RootViewController: UIViewController {

var menu = MenuViewController()
var game = GameViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("root")
    MenuPresent()
}

func GamePresent() {
    self.addChildViewController(game)
    self.view.addSubview((game.view)!)
    game.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}

func MenuPresent() {
    self.addChildViewController(menu)
    self.view.addSubview((menu.view)!)
    menu.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}

func menuDismiss() {
    menu.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
    menu.removeFromParentViewController()
    menu.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

}

MenuViewController:

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController {

//var root = RootViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("menu") 
}
}
```

The print("menu") appears in my console, But the actual view and all assets of the MenuViewController do no appear.

On the other hand my GameViewController and it's SKScene work fine.

[image: MenuViewController]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to know that `SKScene` and `UIViewController` are totally two different things. The hierarchy is typically as following:

`UIViewController` --> `UIView`(`SKView`) --> `SKScene`

So you `SKScene` is presented in a `SKView` which can be a `UIView`, then the `UIView` is presented in a `UIViewController`.

Once you know the hierarchy, everything is easy. There are many ways to use different `UIViewController` for menu and `GameScene` stuff.

**Method One**

For example, you can have a `RootViewController`, a `GameViewController` and a `MenuViewController`. The `RootViewController` is the initial ViewController when the app launches.

In the `RootViewController`, you can create a function to present the `GameViewController`:

```
  func setupGameViewController() {
    self.gameViewController = GameViewController()
    self.addChildViewController(gameViewController!)
    self.view.addSubview((gameViewController!.view)!)
    gameViewController?.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
  }
```

You need to present you `SKScene` in `GameViewController`, I guess you should be familiar with this step.

Then when you need to display the menu, you can add the `MenuViewController` to `RootViewController` with a function like:

```
  func setupMenuViewController() {
    self.menuViewController = MenuViewController()
    self.addChildViewController(menuViewController!)
    self.view.addSubview((menuViewController!.view)!)
    menuViewController?.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
  }
```

You also need to present you menuView in this ViewController, which I suppose you already know.

Also create a function to dismiss the `MenuViewController`:

```
  func removeMenuViewController(){
    self.menuViewController?.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
    self.menuViewController?.removeFromParentViewController()
    self.menuViewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
  }
```

And everything is done.

**Method Two**

You can also have only one `UIViewController`, but create you menu as a `UIView`, then you can use `self.view.addSuview(menuView)` to present your menu. Of course you root view, which is the `self.view as SKView` is still there, but it doesn't matter because it's hidden behind the `menuView`.

**A Note for your updated question**

You cannot remove the scene because the scene is actually `self.view as SKView`, `self.view` is the root view of a UIViewController, it cannot be removed. If you really want to remove you scene (for most cases, it's not necessary), you can create a new `SKView` that present your `SKScene`, then add this `SKView` to your `UIViewController` by `self.view.addSubview(skView)`, when you want to completely remove the scene, just use `skView.removeFromSuperview()`.

Comment: Hi thanks for this answer, I have just implemented it. However, just wondering why you only dismiss the MenuViewController when transitioning away from it but not the GameViewController? Also, just to be clear all the methods you wrote should be in the RootViewController even the dismiss functions?

Comment: @james Of course you can dismiss the `GameViewController` too,  but in most case in my games, I don't want the menu interrupt my game play. So everytime when user click close the menu, they can have the game at exactly the same status when they open the menu view. If you dismiss `GameViewController`, then they will come back with a new initialized game. You can change this behavior accordingly.

Comment: Hopefully, this should be the final aspect of my view problems. In my edited question I show my method one implementation. However, the print statement in the viewDidLoad() works but the view and its elements do not. Not sure what I missed. Thanks.

Comment: @james how did you set you views and all elements in the MenuViewController? cause I didn't see any initialization of that part in the viewDidLoad() function.

Comment: I assumed that: ' self.view.addSubview((menu.view)!) ' would load the base UIView of MenuViewController. So all the elements are just dragged and dropped on that view. But the view or its elements do not appear.

Comment: where do you drop those elements? on storyboard? how does xcode know which view you are setting, does the MenuViewController know which view you added? Have you create a @IBOutlet for everything created in the storyboard?

Comment: I have a separate storyboard for the RootViewController, a separate one for the MenuViewController and a separate one for the GameViewController. The elements are just dragged on to the base UIView of the storyboard. I now think that I misinterpreted your 'method one'. Did you only use one storyboard?

Comment: It doesn't matter how many storyboards you use. I guess you forget to add @IBOutlet of all you elements into the code. If you drag a button in the storyboard, how can the code know there is a button, or what's the reference name the button is. I think you must have missed some basic things there. You cannot drag anything into the storyboard and expect to see them in the app without create a link for them in the code.

Comment: Added the @IBOutlet They still don't appear. Or the View. The print statement still executes.

Comment: self.view.addsubview(mainView) in viewDidLoad()

Comment: also self.view.addsubview(play) in viewDidLoad()

Comment: They both throw a THREAD 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT. Console: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 2):

Views and scenes are two different things. Scenes are held inside of a view. You would have to simply present a scene within your menu view or transition to another view and present an SKScene from there. The code to present the scene might look like this:

```
    let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    scene?.scaleMode = .AspectFit
    skView.presentScene(scene)
```